# Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11835 "Cannot Open"

Tags: swift, streaming, tvos, http-live-streaming, fairplay

I'm currently trying to implement a service to handle DRM with FairPlay streaming on a tvOS App.
Here is my workflow :

1. I get the app certificate as Data
2. From this certificate i get the SPC Datas, using :

   ```
   resourceLoadingRequest.streamingContentKeyRequestData(forApp: applicationCertificate, contentIdentifier: assetIDData, options: resourceLoadingRequestOptions)
   ```
3. From the SPC Datas encoded to base64Data I request POST (with SPC in payload) on our server to get the license which gives me the CKD Datas
4. Then when I get the CKC Datas, I use them as below :

   ```
    guard let dataRequest = resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest else {
       print("no data is being requested in loadingRequest")
       let error = NSError(domain: AssetLoaderDelegate.errorDomain, code: -6, userInfo: nil)
       resourceLoadingRequest.finishLoading(with: error)
       return
    }
    dataRequest.respond(with: datas)
    resourceLoadingRequest.finishLoading()
   ```

But after these steps I get the error :

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11835 "Cannot Open"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170440de0 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-42681 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=This content is not authorized.,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open}

Does anyone have an idea or a tips ?

**Additional infos :**

- the playback process works with non-protected content.
- playerItem.errorLog() returns nil.
- playerItem.status == .failed returns true.
- all the server side process seems to be OK since it's already used for the website and Smart TV.

Comment: I know it's off topic. But can you share how to get `applicationCertificate` please?

Comment: Hi, I am also stuck at this similar problem. Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @Hlung You get Your Application Certificate from a hosted server (recommended) or load into your App Bundle (Testing Purposes) and can gets its Data Bytes and send to ```loadingRequest.streamingContentKeyRequestData(forApp: certificateData, contentIdentifier: assetIdentifierData, options: nil)
``` . Your Certificate should most probably be in .cer format. And you can get its Data Bytes by : 

```let certificateURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "certificate", withExtension: "der"),
        let certificateData = try? Data(contentsOf: certificateURL)```

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this exact same problem.  The problem is the CKC response data returned from `streamingContentKeyRequestData(forApp...` is not just data, it is base 64 encoded string data.  All you need to do is decode it before you respond to the data request:

```swift
 dataRequest.respond(with: Data(base64Encoded: datas)!)
```

For production code you'll want to handle the optionality properly.  Hope this helps!